# How to fetch weekend date i.e. Saturday date between FROM and TO dates in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Suppose if we enter FROM date as `2014-06-01` and TO date as `2014-06-30` then it should fetch dates as `2014-06-07,2014-06-14,2014-06-21 & 2014-06-28.`

Can anyone help me?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Take a look @ [MySQL-site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday)

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through dates and use the function `DAYNAME(date)`. It will return the name of the day on the date passed in as the parameter and you could check to see if it returned 'Saturday'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE DAYNAME(`date_field`)='Saturday'
  AND `date_field` BETWEEN '2014-06-01' AND '2014-06-30'
```

Check [Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname) for DAYNAME function in mySql

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE DAYOFWEEK(`date_field`)='7'
  AND `date_field` BETWEEN '2014-06-01' AND '2014-06-30'
```

Documentation:

```
DAYOFWEEK(date)

Returns the weekday index for date (1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, …, 7 = Saturday). These index values correspond to the ODBC standard
```

Comment: I think you have to change `DAYOFWEEK(date_field)='7'` Instead of `DAYOFWEEK(date_field)='1'` in where condition

Comment: Thanks for notifying the mistake :)

Comment: Tried this.. but EMPTY result :(

Comment: Make sure you have date_field type in date or datetime and not in varchar

Comment: Yes, it is in date type only.

Comment: the code works for me , the result will be empty if you don't have Saturdays date's  in you table